# GNU grep check if input contains a LF character

Tags: grep, newlines

I test content of a set of data files whether they contain at least one of a set of characters which consists of printing and non-printing characters.

My last issue is detecting whether the file contains a line-feed. My *GNU grep 3.0* states every input contains a LF... Why is that?

```
echo -n "test" | grep -UF -e $'\x0a'
```

Any ideas? I suspect some implicit EOL/EOF interference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

grep is line-oriented - if the input does not end with a newline, it still considers the text past the last newline (or start of file) as a line.

Line-oriented programs are a poor fit for directly processing binary files - they will often have pathological cases if a binary file has a particularly long "line".

Instead, consider something like a combination of `tr` and `cmp`:

```
$ echo -n foo | tr -d -c $'\n' | cmp /dev/null - 
# no output and exits with status 0

$ echo foo | tr -d -c $'\n' | cmp /dev/null -
cmp: EOF on /dev/null which is empty
# exits with status 1
```

This method also has the advantage of needing to read the input only up to the first newline character (plus buffering).

Comment: Just a side note: `man tr` mentions the way how to specify the non-printing characters - via octal value `\NNN`

Comment: But buffering will actually mean that it needs to read something like 4096 lines before `tr` starts to output anything (see `seq 5000 | strace -e write tr -cd '\n' > /dev/null`)

Answer (score 3):

From [the POSIX specification of `grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html):

> Regular expression matching shall be based on text lines. Since a `<newline>` separates or terminates patterns [...], regular expressions cannot contain a `<newline>`. Similarly, since patterns are matched against individual lines (excluding the terminating `<newline>` characters) of the input, there is no way for a pattern to match a `<newline>` found in the input.

To check whether input contains a linefeed character, which is the same as a newline character on Unix, you may count the number of lines with `wc -l`:

```
lines=$( wc -l <inputfile )
if [ "$lines" -gt 0 ]; then
    echo 'Input had a linefeed character in it'
fi
```

Or, if you have a string:

```
lines=$( printf '%s' "$string" | wc -l )
# etc.
```

Comment: @StephenKitt Check the manual page. Among other things, "This option has no effect on platforms other than MS-DOS  and  MS-Windows" makes it pretty clear that this is not the case.

Comment: Oh right sorry, it only strips CRs, right.